# Averaging time-stamped data hourly in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I've average distance travelled data `meters` for several days and times of the year. Here's how the dataset I'm working with looks like:

```
> print(datanet)
      Date & Time [Local]     meters
   1: 2017-06-01 00:00:14   2.333355
   2: 2017-06-01 01:00:13   6.952414
   3: 2017-06-01 02:00:30  61.727543
   4: 2017-06-01 03:00:15 235.873883
   5: 2017-06-01 04:00:15 138.136375
  ---                               
1428: 2017-07-30 19:00:21  40.602983
1429: 2017-07-30 20:00:47  34.292888
1430: 2017-07-30 21:00:20 303.478297
1431: 2017-07-30 22:00:18   5.741059
```

Now, I would like to transform this table so that it provides the average distance travelled for each hour of the day from `0` to `23`, based on data from multiple days. Here's the code I've been using for that purpose (additionally includes an `sd` column):

```
data_travel<-datanet %>% 
  mutate(
    date = ymd_hms(`Date & Time [Local]`),
    hour = hour(date)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(hour) %>%
  summarise(
    avg_meters = mean(meters),
    sd_meters = sd(meters)
  )
```

This works, but sadly the last hour of the day `23` always shows `NA` values:

```
> head(data_travel[19:24,])
# A tibble: 6 x 3
   hour avg_meters sd_meters
  <int>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1    18       57.4     109. 
2    19       96.5     177. 
3    20      121.      248. 
4    21      141.      299. 
5    22       76.4      86.4
6    23       NA       NaN
```

Does somebody have an idea of how I could modify this code so that I also get the average distance travelled `avg_meters` and `sd` for hour `23`? Any input is appreciated!

````
> dput(datanet[1:700,])
structure(list(`Date & Time [Local]` = structure(c(1464732013, 
1464735613, 1464739229, 1464742813, 1464746413, 1464750018, 1464753629, 
1464757213, 1464760813, 1464764430, 1464768013, 1464771629, 1464775214, 
1464778818, 1464782429, 1464786013, 1464789623, 1464793214, 1464796813, 
1464800413, 1464804029, 1464807612, 1464811213, 1464814830, 1464818411, 
1464822013, 1464825629, 1464829213, 1464832812, 1464836417, 1464840021, 
1464843612, 1464847211, 1464850830, 1464854412, 1464858030, 1464861629, 
1464865211, 1464868814, 1464872416, 1464876030, 1464879611, 1464883212, 
1464886811, 1464890430, 1464894017, 1464897611, 1464901217, 1464904830, 
1464908419, 1464912011, 1464915610, 1464919207, 1464922850, 1464926410, 
1464930004, 1464933623, 1464937249, 1464940811, 1464944410, 1464948011, 
1464951629, 1464955218, 1464958811, 1464962430, 1464966018, 1464969610, 
1464973214, 1464976848, 1464980410, 1464984010, 1464987610, 1464991230, 
1464994811, 1464998409, 1465002003, 1465005610, 1465009222, 1465012817, 
1465016402, 1465020030, 1465023618, 1465027214, 1465030846, 1465034419, 
1465038020, 1465041690, 1465045212, 1465048849, 1465052409, 1465056029, 
1465059617, 1465063209, 1465066830, 1465070410, 1465074009, 1465077630, 
1465081240, 1465084804, 1465088401, 1465092010, 1465095622, 1465099222, 
1465102852, 1465106449, 1465110010, 1465113612, 1465117270, 1465120849, 
1465124408, 1465128011, 1465131617, 1465135230, 1465138848, 1465142408, 
1465146008, 1465149612, 1465153250, 1465156808, 1465160427, 1465164016, 
1465167601, 1465171229, 1465174830, 1465178415, 1465182054, 1465185656, 
1465189209, 1465192807, 1465196422, 1465200029, 1465203732, 1465207230, 
1465210848, 1465214408, 1465218050, 1465221629, 1465225216, 1465228823, 
1465232415, 1465236015, 1465239615, 1465243256, 1465246830, 1465250414, 
1465254008, 1465257629, 1465261214, 1465264814, 1465268449, 1465272007, 
1465275630, 1465279255, 1465282845, 1465286460, 1465290013, 1465293617, 
1465297226, 1465300814, 1465304418, 1465308029, 1465311614, 1465315214, 
1465318814, 1465322429, 1465326007, 1465329607, 1465333213, 1465336813, 
1465340422, 1465344013, 1465347615, 1465351230, 1465354813, 1465358413, 
1465362014, 1465365630, 1465369216, 1465372830, 1465376413, 1465380013, 
1465383606, 1465387230, 1465390817, 1465394430, 1465398013, 1465401613, 
1465405213, 1465408829, 1465412411, 1465416013, 1465419613, 1465423229, 
1465426812, 1465430412, 1465434011, 1465437614, 1465441224, 1465444812, 
1465448413, 1465452013, 1465455629, 1465459213, 1465462817, 1465466430, 
1465470011, 1465473611, 1465477211, 1465480830, 1465484412, 1465488012, 
1465491611, 1465495230, 1465498820, 1465502426, 1465506011, 1465509606, 
1465513212, 1465516830, 1465520419, 1465524003, 1465527611, 1465531227, 
1465534850, 1465538403, 1465542010, 1465545612, 1465549229, 1465552811, 
1465556425, 1465560011, 1465563611, 1465567227, 1465570819, 1465574430, 
1465578018, 1465581610, 1465585210, 1465588830, 1465592418, 1465596009, 
1465599602, 1465603209, 1465606829, 1465610450, 1465614009, 1465617609, 
1465621210, 1465624817, 1465628422, 1465632017, 1465635610, 1465639210, 
1465642829, 1465646417, 1465650008, 1465653630, 1465657209, 1465660813, 
1465664451, 1465668003, 1465671609, 1465675228, 1465678816, 1465682409, 
1465686002, 1465689608, 1465693229, 1465696816, 1465700401, 1465704008, 
1465707629, 1465711217, 1465714809, 1465718429, 1465722016, 1465725608, 
1465729201, 1465732830, 1465736415, 1465740024, 1465743630, 1465747215, 
1465750811, 1465754430, 1465758016, 1465761607, 1465765230, 1465768828, 
1465772415, 1465776016, 1465779613, 1465783260, 1465786808, 1465790414, 
1465794014, 1465797659, 1465801216, 1465804807, 1465808430, 1465812030, 
1465815614, 1465819220, 1465822816, 1465826408, 1465830029, 1465833613, 
1465837215, 1465840829, 1465844414, 1465848008, 1465851627, 1465855213, 
1465858814, 1465862414, 1465866029, 1465869607, 1465873207, 1465876814, 
1465880429, 1465884015, 1465887630, 1465891207, 1465894815, 1465898429, 
1465902014, 1465905614, 1465909218, 1465912824, 1465916413, 1465920013, 
1465923618, 1465927229, 1465930813, 1465934413, 1465938013, 1465941613, 
1465945229, 1465948811, 1465952412, 1465956022, 1465959626, 1465963214, 
1465966830, 1465970412, 1465974030, 1465977606, 1465981230, 1465984813, 
1465988429, 1465992012, 1465995613, 1465999229, 1466002812, 1466006404, 
1466010012, 1466013626, 1466017211, 1466020830, 1466024412, 1466028012, 
1466031619, 1466035211, 1466038813, 1466042430, 1466046004, 1466049612, 
1466053212, 1466056830, 1466060420, 1466064026, 1466067603, 1466071211, 
1466074829, 1466078410, 1466082019, 1466085619, 1466089211, 1466092804, 
1466096429, 1466100011, 1466103611, 1466107230, 1466110821, 1466114422, 
1466118009, 1466121611, 1466125234, 1466128803, 1466132412, 1466136027, 
1466139610, 1466143210, 1466146834, 1466150410, 1466154034, 1466157609, 
1466161210, 1466164834, 1466168403, 1466172007, 1466175620, 1466179202, 
1466182802, 1466186433, 1466190020, 1466193609, 1466197209, 1466200802, 
1466204433, 1466208009, 1466211609, 1466215202, 1466218854, 1466222419, 
1466226009, 1466229634, 1466233208, 1466236811, 1466240426, 1466244008, 
1466247608, 1466251234, 1466254826, 1466258409, 1466262008, 1466265609, 
1466269233, 1466272808, 1466276408, 1466280011, 1466283647, 1466287216, 
1466290808, 1466294408, 1466298033, 1466301601, 1466305210, 1466308825, 
1466312407, 1466316009, 1466319634, 1466323208, 1466326833, 1466330408, 
1466334007, 1466337633, 1466341210, 1466344834, 1466348419, 1466352015, 
1466355616, 1466359223, 1466362820, 1466366415, 1466370014, 1466373622, 
1466377205, 1466380815, 1466384414, 1466388033, 1466391608, 1466395206, 
1466398833, 1466402415, 1466406017, 1466409634, 1466413214, 1466416817, 
1466420431, 1466424008, 1466427615, 1466431234, 1466434813, 1466438434, 
1466442013, 1466445614, 1466449207, 1466452835, 1466456413, 1466460013, 
1466463613, 1466467213, 1466470834, 1466474413, 1466478014, 1466481633, 
1466485223, 1466488806, 1466492416, 1466496035, 1466499613, 1466503206, 
1466506835, 1466510412, 1466514012, 1466517635, 1466521213, 1466524823, 
1466528413, 1466532010, 1466535605, 1466539234, 1466542812, 1466546405, 
1466550012, 1466553612, 1466557234, 1466560813, 1466564412, 1466568035, 
1466571605, 1466575214, 1466578835, 1466582412, 1466586012, 1466589605, 
1466593222, 1466596811, 1466600412, 1466604005, 1466607629, 1466611212, 
1466614811, 1466618430, 1466622019, 1466625612, 1466629230, 1466632820, 
1466636411, 1466640010, 1466643629, 1466647213, 1466650811, 1466654430, 
1466658019, 1466661619, 1466665218, 1466668812, 1466672430, 1466676011, 
1466679610, 1466683220, 1466686830, 1466690419, 1466694010, 1466697614, 
1466701247, 1466704818, 1466708411, 1466712028, 1466715618, 1466719203, 
1466722810, 1466726423, 1466730010, 1466733609, 1466737223, 1466740817, 
1466744403, 1466748031, 1466751617, 1466755210, 1466758811, 1466762411, 
1466766030, 1466769619, 1466773212, 1466776847, 1466780417, 1466784009, 
1466787609, 1466791231, 1466794818, 1466798409, 1466802010, 1466805609, 
1466809230, 1466812817, 1466816401, 1466820009, 1466823660, 1466827217, 
1466830831, 1466834409, 1466838008, 1466841619, 1466845216, 1466848808, 
1466852404, 1466856021, 1466859616, 1466863232, 1466866808, 1466870408, 
1466874011, 1466877630, 1466881215, 1466884818, 1466888417, 1466892019, 
1466895616, 1466899207, 1466902809, 1466906430, 1466910016, 1466913611, 
1466917226, 1466920821, 1466924416, 1466928008, 1466931622, 1466935231, 
1466938815, 1466942431, 1466946015, 1466949629, 1466953215, 1466956808, 
1466960415, 1466964030, 1466967614, 1466971215, 1466974812, 1466978430, 
1466982014, 1466985614, 1466989208, 1466992830, 1466996413, 1467000014, 
1467003614, 1467007230, 1467010814, 1467014415, 1467018015, 1467021630, 
1467025214, 1467028830, 1467032415, 1467036030, 1467039614, 1467043206, 
1467046815, 1467050430, 1467054012, 1467057613, 1467061213, 1467064814, 
1467068430, 1467072013, 1467075608, 1467079250, 1467082814, 1467086414, 
1467090007, 1467093629, 1467097214, 1467100824, 1467104413, 1467108013, 
1467111630, 1467115213, 1467118813, 1467122429, 1467126006, 1467129613, 
1467133213, 1467136829, 1467140412, 1467144013, 1467147613, 1467151214, 
1467154829, 1467158410, 1467162027, 1467165605, 1467169212, 1467172813, 
1467176428, 1467180012, 1467183619, 1467187220, 1467190812, 1467194405, 
1467198012, 1467201629, 1467205218, 1467208830, 1467212411, 1467216004, 
1467219611, 1467223211, 1467226829, 1467230411, 1467234012, 1467237612, 
1467241229, 1467244811, 1467248405), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), meters = c(7.24497992499657, 4.87741163537199, 
9.08560044628181, 80.6842320881314, 238.606484922097, 157.204921816723, 
625.23872908032, 219.35778781259, 12.6588736944506, 93.8090439559674, 
319.445131807673, 67.8036768396769, 804.804836152127, 109.434600933436, 
129.949236899749, 105.911149760734, 27.9531918089091, 11.27836453714, 
457.093853355937, 26.5240927781247, 19.7015020304213, 14.3532653640863, 
1.25853679670009, 0.150718694512225, 1.70366003911483, 2.63870002711148, 
127.037462401145, 961.452700995197, 215.04628486518, 48.3476802703997, 
56.4299311045402, 71.0567210386123, 53.2157129067539, 80.4040760406296, 
236.078682140782, 406.948035573002, 92.6423364709784, 403.797511366086, 
323.858212895809, 65.9783289318472, 26.7161400634748, 21.4406886404941, 
44.6906704150594, 36.0784092780547, 66.4678272178005, 68.0358199816987, 
2.1476323514823, 3.01587341033808, 1.57380761082474, 1.71653324348141, 
18.8397076847765, 184.268772826548, 61.2103183204004, 82.9010640232318, 
43.7120771884048, 40.4214303580113, 220.354835462908, 77.5844706628055, 
10.6522275628958, 64.6401569172547, 170.237028243589, 235.781539666942, 
206.150503465281, 25.3213069661311, 36.7436253838348, 9.83110790227874, 
23.3459053606757, 3.45271958972457, 1.96114320043511, 20.4049146593214, 
15.2372682099889, 20.3543121890185, 42.7350584816069, 12.1313207862892, 
1.11708614676525, 191.836648404227, 33.3046462595366, 166.168666618136, 
31.1722631768611, 133.717766242875, 12.0334817161546, 62.2359071313657, 
16.7484729490856, 109.549479467076, 438.080739581294, 37.0971614841641, 
105.391252306762, 122.494788370234, 88.6622245013997, 24.3191344096727, 
5.117649955497, 51.9358625225939, 47.9478783281661, 6.96463276369705, 
1.75025309899143, 31.176657161161, 10.1169843733554, 26.5346636683759, 
15.9584899969855, 337.838831129694, 59.7693703670957, 46.7853809521572, 
16.799710673628, 39.1979373391332, 122.408881979713, 266.855999717221, 
63.8055787186155, 57.9900269187913, 120.78876572575, 82.1213040340665, 
105.298734249817, 161.923229191297, 28.9509612131438, 0.248722765246352, 
6.42826019283635, 4.80096922046293, 7.66924438494585, 3.77931970556652, 
6.16226345339552, 1.89180927192504, 2.92660299028088, 4.47513027348909, 
5.3772236196912, 258.79885256986, 76.3673624568927, 227.248769639605, 
119.571707120552, 35.7102849958032, 36.9949248244319, 137.90048603805, 
96.6658682838857, 259.080913058415, 105.606050276669, 56.1002922989478, 
85.2381765021222, 191.363093870704, 55.7981801107081, 12.9578924739909, 
26.3419895578265, 14.4503596334286, 15.6675803413194, 21.9669267962415, 
63.1276880372023, 5.54867147176836, 9.0179124542279, 7.13599657582419, 
69.6648263961824, 352.989183299746, 263.287397250075, 253.766882591523, 
209.967849272818, 73.9692977527144, 98.0159993160327, 170.190795021595, 
282.190504225449, 78.6666650047386, 27.0630775295066, 332.829084995611, 
194.938072897224, 102.422860453484, 17.7992858642505, 13.1266890679012, 
4.58091256610204, 6.40555894626406, 2.66715489350561, 19.248878078399, 
14.0807810821772, 4.57816759344819, 4.40196859830686, 10.7329317290172, 
32.4528952520776, 138.596548507858, 125.547606032588, 46.3652014291144, 
16.3797234392651, 10.249071010749, 248.440266699442, 304.347056271548, 
154.412296810916, 46.8081932028809, 226.453483692211, 431.805061221221, 
111.437754042661, 217.641929376792, 25.1923986792615, 12.2256823484931, 
12.2949586884092, 31.0958526630604, 85.5575841303107, 22.7975660566324, 
30.5216893316272, 35.1775681936213, 9.50846937534727, 9.76657486076715, 
0.579469646956765, 266.224607309967, 188.727073099707, 292.559096086872, 
9.49743703683714, 107.113753739463, 175.681846441223, 19.379648871926, 
88.2778253322274, 410.496903513497, 8.97162022276979, 32.4619475881012, 
73.646386222969, 75.348171202073, 90.8515841171699, 10.6200903372279, 
3.02379387011622, 32.825022046837, 65.550868227495, 24.9833819842075, 
77.5493346217115, 2.10544392843427, 2.32222002989636, 3.12605565461408, 
1.02518236594501, 341.46710436094, 151.588096225148, 353.933570258634, 
124.173972566209, 60.4110080957218, 38.5295043269143, 154.717374816579, 
10.642332114307, 112.19511336859, 178.656934678561, 144.883837500965, 
193.991868696415, 202.99316836535, 77.6189915466929, 0.871460936515423, 
1.63576829944789, 47.5439446635587, 60.241399209101, 92.7059630247652, 
1.71653312232677, 3.28998417221502, 16.9888823353554, 1.073227079111, 
31.3529682130551, 98.2633746496518, 146.311948071212, 277.215271024987, 
30.6004645511119, 49.4907657584358, 17.6377880041836, 517.661457540348, 
581.555783536356, 1010.85341607138, 101.36421835411, 101.587448595859, 
144.303729077564, 91.3938747436922, 149.518556866971, 36.3308699793953, 
7.80121835979054, 23.0312990229266, 13.41048184825, 20.339107047676, 
3.08847373655867, 31.7536206163432, 80.5523050297356, 5.57519986215111, 
12.7301911126705, 265.400347490029, 96.389278202961, 96.4450196328944, 
269.701595926116, 40.1994744716222, 185.194247845766, 132.799182823423, 
92.6508846479433, 31.7196753780259, 82.6725380176083, 149.907487149117, 
259.995942351777, 136.962271891916, 47.7342981878729, 28.0369643012698, 
23.5176540297538, 85.9823208879668, 69.1793641133218, 2.10460736024825, 
2.47507980743031, 1.46820616137708, 8.50065507425538, 9.43358037894557, 
15.0643556352927, 160.034358372113, 401.192221112903, 208.507212166668, 
16.9012427928657, 70.1561153179486, 282.055943502233, 95.7582280566781, 
20.4921115795782, 224.297864971227, 248.751359316637, 63.3008262529409, 
202.381548954774, 160.240208598145, 89.2596850671307, 2.41266014760612, 
2.24662537954621, 92.0812846530431, 64.0782727558696, 102.539355421441, 
133.192603215476, 2.19161459176181, 2.71657087565203, 2.60259248593429, 
9.95223133490391, 175.102558714441, 102.128569321102, 45.1350310564478, 
60.7860248161304, 166.511239966959, 32.3622524770883, 38.1126859517567, 
169.914906248272, 165.51479143087, 21.6290787183546, 154.863792200668, 
224.650919723327, 172.786068029272, 41.6201741515014, 40.966552071361, 
60.9998953906058, 4.00012706993277, 79.9578066806101, 183.917814759389, 
103.086558986388, 6.96826209073272, 5.74403906883466, 5.4856515067938, 
28.6736690417882, 238.403484773501, 231.70110714268, 126.348996131178, 
61.4905557699149, 104.389974082626, 246.69389506543, 79.3069202652704, 
24.117595869327, 48.4779179700019, 69.4483313003939, 127.606317513607, 
78.8710394107804, 98.1528155665254, 128.061282053331, 3.19606373207204, 
1.87066709355931, 30.3658567894746, 67.1163251638405, 32.6323314265454, 
0.228514489291685, 2.59419308146204, 6.96463324671082, 31.4857435059086, 
32.2152666766542, 219.54173457463, 100.503943180343, 71.9061154834901, 
91.2830509779235, 155.03560958018, 98.391102232677, 27.4736388446992, 
34.7344995015586, 85.1266347031687, 74.6245520597207, 24.0060703654787, 
139.030754853487, 171.244448038257, 112.193936557097, 2.39299360914121, 
19.4583131438491, 58.7443921590234, 14.0595780932243, 216.575414578798, 
127.459683665046, 26.4468118443774, 15.7904069541748, 3.42889322639363, 
18.9364897049987, 137.67183581274, 122.967226389734, 119.894430382828, 
104.442282446888, 190.221376118256, 131.941577184786, 353.399746658368, 
448.477151206068, 133.358287719838, 261.649707603195, 81.4006720251283, 
343.002058701936, 163.91259720329, 197.994167334045, 7.30944634184061, 
7.26330302571758, 32.2642168570983, 330.892281390864, 76.9551034586096, 
16.5345940654105, 93.4833973060589, 2.44622725450917, 1.07860556492395, 
1.93778399725422, 77.9570596409594, 94.0913633507909, 56.7576348472931, 
409.330409688539, 51.8605115857434, 101.399915620214, 186.284262562234, 
150.206902386026, 73.7756320461831, 29.7407716653824, 148.98703547435, 
220.790713913921, 244.515597043242, 18.6165511888937, 9.90234122916165, 
33.2562502415159, 156.414444934157, 13.9779124860658, 48.9122633130083, 
170.372846084158, 157.591584502432, 41.3319249226387, 14.1513887931616, 
6.44142678100409, 228.471931226893, 110.023055666621, 33.5052868559644, 
173.194133068492, 32.3931156891464, 44.5888695638585, 57.8480536590698, 
130.274156166872, 79.3730952009515, 46.5247317494093, 113.821030825373, 
345.300064595988, 152.140595169695, 17.0421460982582, 6.84417297878845, 
12.5696620896434, 36.6545290246341, 74.6452657675716, 217.14457420751, 
165.496335573275, 22.3871316935213, 6.61421665015, 20.0410769731539, 
23.7057126539467, 168.517094664878, 110.986727962072, 83.3281747496762, 
7.35167504947444, 76.5528141698817, 20.6384141732761, 87.00310582216, 
402.411224410847, 145.210679361704, 55.1206401339897, 446.103457643039, 
95.317801637148, 198.306682822754, 88.7652010770343, 4.4779529467687, 
55.2357786872407, 118.400174413319, 163.550512253059, 103.789889510405, 
70.1485296476271, 44.9031868790507, 5.42285572703366, 23.2710355323781, 
7.96212769344129, 37.560076557467, 210.670533114753, 104.544578996089, 
438.121243591053, 56.4263114090557, 30.3428605030646, 102.704223497357, 
88.0554172082872, 29.8261947342531, 21.3578133423672, 125.139532314134, 
199.2412154636, 423.415414756748, 155.583267038193, 2.14393350563694, 
2.77638044593597, 25.6375785864043, 176.271312482445, 188.095709294767, 
162.049988299195, 28.6407159601821, 341.238744680548, 6.70617205440293, 
0.685237342195351, 72.5497248411768, 411.366138460536, 14.570194300977, 
35.8331305489166, 336.776755084208, 43.10843602833, 343.590748922672, 
306.997839886018, 110.223009494854, 246.067728815614, 229.160642943454, 
80.1932202086262, 223.436937319274, 7.33591020042729, 3.91210855110157, 
0.301852508403949, 1.9831582085811, 100.093808999808, 136.307291596312, 
56.0971664553408, 35.91142300096, 35.9638499452433, 2.71553679684771, 
4.6621428025371, 140.593157625054, 274.807479865085, 221.786077846005, 
61.483885141769, 20.3881339787884, 30.7758272593722, 96.0458882470437, 
246.919746334924, 22.0033859138399, 198.28605047425, 103.814293419658, 
46.5348985729046, 29.182847412964, 75.8648063336849, 13.8241139461049, 
17.1286557911254, 88.1810161018373, 3.36013813866121, 69.639752829193, 
677.723130883346, 41.0286431704323, 73.2159389655071, 2.97198914835809, 
2.2955645498568, 77.4338889708046, 165.144080335453, 28.249849842644, 
697.335948561217, 26.764915418294, 14.2190768683659, 91.7637857701146, 
27.5440244171723, 16.8445374971489, 23.8566496302873, 0.981943140947041, 
78.5997636834095, 162.138462101107, 44.1672067123073, 1.57379999898296, 
4.52584675687701, 0.97658119252377, 0.477360675618112, 129.151103972441, 
70.8307163818214, 275.971859788928, 127.881236082799, 1.170287338146, 
0.866454371283992, 434.919703422169, 93.8451377376139, 207.10904118958, 
46.8316256828644, 150.387134794503, 278.399451505872, 198.814569340003, 
115.184928188408, 36.753170014185, 129.106822541989, 168.482550085438, 
92.1323337766019, 250.394018594269, 37.1881210650176, 26.0619948566024, 
2.1015758585879, 1.9337619910658, 2.5374401085012, 6.88084629859044, 
240.364952743281, 23.3347433113824, 12.8301991435217, 104.664097883855, 
11.9543330584122, 299.693093901171, 457.205452556256, 166.486441167246, 
479.147896086039, 601.250116553193, 324.328442697521, 329.307886840488, 
231.36130846456, 34.9248512789383, 159.724908476382, 310.307623928807, 
665.667745992218, 440.34793375254, 47.0987434639045, 3.27176941323539, 
9.70137304643561, 10.0607743796965, 3.08631438745061, 85.9070751173181, 
114.552594829497, 56.4422079169895, 72.8598000828185, 49.5713482843566, 
2.63222698246548, 278.660159682918, 374.155025716734, 614.896477070897, 
84.7023024801914, 112.319999024275, 18.5987593461749, 82.9077768700278, 
154.845742871174, 125.567795777075, 66.4893506450749, 126.741063662877, 
82.2411837719443, 756.335890510717, 73.1151790189073, 3.5922959646701, 
8.41573329417288, 4.41473763601453, 2.12491629471561, 57.10162180489, 
51.9326111578832, 58.8698849597487, 64.1069702907545, 25.653260586019, 
2.25452824419408, 133.78927961757, 341.7548293499, 14.113318950603, 
64.7040755111393, 74.5271989167769, 407.725534601351, 309.316524308558, 
20.2280966869265, 23.8884632436018, 20.0051667649045, 23.3715363806949, 
21.8895053097727, 284.299801015909, 133.058636731235, 9.13435639512076, 
8.93531290420054, 6.97575634977357, 38.5847487365879, 322.899303421944, 
7.43662008052574, 31.3472739232612, 90.172402886085, 13.1780473878919, 
11.8113106256799, 95.4868454357865, 111.151536039587, 62.3434590358668, 
25.3913623754508, 152.028407407367, 140.924105429548, 110.376776160796, 
21.9269046506022, 282.56001268775, 26.9210719144184, 88.3343050027196, 
291.612562587322, 164.906755082596, 116.426543798048, 16.3087551310383, 
6.52751999940019, 9.01631759743765, 16.1907026689521, 16.5315572289726, 
1.88226712179479, 18.0388366074334, 48.3907627589146, 1.49068315465064, 
9.44594654212787, 730.702774263893)), row.names = c(NA, -700L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002641ef0>)
```
````

Comment: Could you `dput` your (sample) data? (That would allow simpler reproducibility)

Comment: Try `mean(meters, na.rm = T)` and `sd(meters, na.rm  = T)`

Comment: @niko Just updated with a `dput()` sample of the data

Comment: @Sonny That worked!

Comment: @juancda4 Cool, Added that as an answer

Comment: @Sonny approved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `meters` field might have NA values.

Hence adding `na.rm = T` to `mean` and `sd` functions will solve this.